# What are the ways to model bi-modal target distribution

Tags: machine-learning, descriptive-statistics, bimodal

The target i am trying to regress is clearly a bi-modal distribution, currently one standalone model is giving results which are satisfactory.

As I am seeking improvement on my present model, I want to know whether there are specific ways in which we can learn a bi-modal target distribution.

Answer (score 2):

What about fiting a mixture? E.g. mixture of two gaussians? You may want to look at our tags [mixture](/questions/tagged/mixture) and [gaussian-mixture](/questions/tagged/gaussian-mixture).